# Bind automatic delete dns record if host down

Tags: dns, bind, failover

I have 2 load balancers for my web service.
This load balancers hide from roundrobin DNS.
I one NLB down client can use another dns record from dns and connect via alive NLB server.
I want change this scheme to something like this:
if NLB A down my DNS server BIND delete DNS record for this NLB and give to clients only DNS record to alive secondary NLB
How to configure this scheme via bins or another open source DNS server?

Comment: What does "down" mean?

Comment: I mean situation when first load balancer not working.